# Angular2 AOT compiler error, duplicate identificeren PropertyKey

Tags: angular, systemjs, aot, angular2-aot

Im compiling my angular2 project AA described here:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html

Im running the following command:  node_modules/.bin/ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json

But in getting the following error:
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.core.d.ts:17:14: Duplicate identifier 'PropertyKey'.

Domeinen have any Idea hoe to Fix organisatie hoe to find out here is is declareren multiple Times?

Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself. the problem was in de typings i was using. I installed a bunch of typings on different ways. so what did i do.

- Remove typings folder from the project en the typings.json file
- Remove any typings dependecies from the packages.json expect the following 2:
- @types/jasmine and @types/node, if you dont know what version you can   install them with the following command:
  `npm install @types/jasmine --save-dev and npm install @types/node --save-dev`
- After that i recompiled with aot and the error was gone i had some other missing typings and i installed them with @types, i think it is important to not use other commands than @types.